# C:\fakepath\image.jpg how to upload a local file to an html file input

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a drag and drop image uploader. However, I have found that when receiving the local file path, the browser reads something along the lines of 
`C:\fakepath\image.jpg`.

I assume this is a security feature for the browser.

Is there a more secure way that I should be approaching this? If not, What is the work around?

Here is the code I am working with.

#### Script

```
handlePhotoChange = e => {
    const photo = e.target.value;
    let file = new File([""], photo);
}
```

#### HTML

```
<input type="file"
    name="photo"
    id="photo"
    accept="image/*"
    onChange={this.handlePhotoChange}
    className="create-content__form--upload" 
/>
```

Comment: `let file = e.target.files[0]`.

Comment: @Kaiido You are probably correct. OP simply needs to access the `FileList` and get the `File`

Comment: Yes that was correct. I was trying to create a new file, which wasn't necessary. @Kaiido , this works perfectly.